# What does 'feed off' mean?

Tags: idioms

> The whole language of love had been corrupted by overuse. When I listened to the radio in the car, my love **fed** effortlessly **off** the love songs that happened to be playing, for example, **off** the passion of a black American female singer, whose accent I took on (I was on an empty motorway) while Chloe became the lady's 'baby'.
>
> Wouldn't it be nice 
>   To hold you in my arms 
>   And love you, baby? 
>   To hold you in my arms
>   Oh yeah and I say, I do, I say I love you, baby?
>
> (Alain de Botton, On Love pp.75-6)

Is *feed off* an idiom as is said, “eat something in particular customarily. (Of is usually retained before pronouns ([thefreedictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/feed+off))“? But it seems to be kind of strange in the context. So I got this guess: it is not an idiom but a construction of ‘feed + resultative prepositional phrase’. I mean his love fed/heard the love songs and got totally distasted for them. How do I have to understand it?

Comment: bees feed off flower nectar, and cows feed off grassy pastures...

Comment: @SF.You’ve hit exactly my itching point! Now I got the usage of ‘off’ which is as same as yours in [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/off?s=t) - preposition.29,30. Thank you very much.

Comment: I think your (incorrect) understanding arises because you're trying to interpret the *second* sentence as amplifying the *first*. But actually, that first sentence is really a "heading" for both the remainder of the paragraph *and several more following*, which you haven't quoted here. So while the first sentence is *negative* about "the language of love", the rest of that paragraph just relates how the author himself has been "willingly seduced" by it (in *positive* terms). Questions and negativity reappear in the *next* paragraph (which is an integral part of the ***full*** context).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a common phrasal verb construction, and I don't think it qualifies as an idiom. In the case of something abstract or nonliving, such as love, the subject is personified and figuratively consumes [part of; in poetic usage the feeding is often non-destructive] the object.

To *feed off* (or on) something is to *draw strength or sustenance* from it, and need not involve literally eating the object. [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/feed-off) and [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/feed-off-on-sth) have this as a standard entry. I think this meaning descends in a sensible fashion from the definition of *feed*.

To be sure, the relevant definition is not the most common or first listed one, which is literal eating. See:

- [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/feed); tr. 4, 5; intr. 2, 3
- [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/feed); 4, 5
- [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/feed); 1.7, 2